# Хранение токена

Tags: java, android, token

Какие средства в `Android` лучше использовать для хранения токена, пароля и прочих данных пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По заявлению Android хранить токены безопасно в [Shared Preferences](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php). Небезопасно это на рутованных устройствах, ибо там к файлу Shared Preferences можно получить доступ (без рута андройд не пускает в папку приложения).

Так что если что-то серьезное - то лучше шифровать. Как шифровать?

[Продолжение читай тут](https://toster.ru/q/417596)

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач существует [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). Он упрощает работу с токенами, паролями и другими данными пользователя. Для примера позволяет автоматически обновлять токен если тот устарел.